# Como cargar info de MySQL en Entries de Tkinter haciendo doble clic en elemento Listbox compuesto por dos columnas

Tags: mysql, python, tkinter, mariadb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En esta GUI lo que hay son unos Entries que lo que hacen es permitir ingresar información para ser almacenada en una base de datos MySQL. El Listbox básicamente visualiza uno de los campos de la base de datos (el nombre), que de hecho es uno de los Entry.

Además, al hacer doble clic sobre uno de los elementos del Listbox todos los Entry se cargan con la información correspondiente de la base de datos. Pero, lo que intento conseguir es mostrar el nombre junto al apellido, y que al dar doble clic sobre uno de estos haga la misma acción: cargar la información acorde a cada campo Entry.

Este es el código que carga los nombres en el Listbox. Comentado se encuentra la opción para visualizar los nombres y los apellidos:

```
def cargar_lista():
    try:
        connect.commit()
        display = "SELECT p_nombres, p_apellidos FROM propietarios order by p_nombres"
        cursor.execute(display)
        registros = cursor.fetchall()
        lb.delete(0, END)
        for item in registros:
            nombres = item[0]
            apellidos = item[1]
            #lb.insert(END, nombres)
            lb.insert(END, nombres + ' ' + apellidos)
    except:
        showerror ("Mensaje", "Error al cargar los propietarios.")
```

Y este es parte del código que carga la información en los Entries:

```
def llenar_campos():
    i = lb.curselection()[0]
    valor = lb.get(i)
    edit = """SELECT * FROM propietarios WHERE p_nombres=("%s");""" % (valor)
    cursor.execute(edit)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    connect.commit()
    for item in result:
        d1 = item[1] #CC/nit
        d2 = item[2] #título
        d3 = item[3] #Fingreso
        d4 = item[4] #razón social
        d5 = item[5] #Ciudad
        d6 = item[6] #Nombres
        d7 = item[7] #Apellidos
        d8 = item[8] #Dir casa
        d9 = item[9] #Teléfono
        d10 = item[10] #Dir oficina
        d11 = item[11] #Tel oficina
        d12 = item[12] #Fax
        d13 = item[13] #Email

        cedula.set(d1)
        titulo.set(d2)
        ingreso.set(d3)
        rsocial.set(d4)
        residencia.set(d5)
        nombres.set(d6)
        apellidos.set(d7)
        direccion.set(d8)
        telefono.set(d9)
        oficina.set(d10)
        tel.set(d11)
        telfax.set(d12)
        correo.set(d13)

        bloquear() #Bloquea los Entries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bién lo que quieres es que teniendo un ListView que contiene una lista de nombres completos (nombre+apellidos) obtener los nombres y los apellidos del propietario seleccionado en el ListView por separados para poder hacer una consulta en la bd con esos datos. Tienes varias opciones:

- Usar un separador entre el nombre (o nombres) y los apellidos para parsear posteriormente sin problemas usando `split`. Típicamente se usa una coma:

  ```
  lb.insert(END, nombres + ', ' + apellidos)
  ```

  Esto te dejaría un ListBox algo así:

  > PAOLA, SEPÚLVEDA MENDEZ
  >   ROSA ELENA, GARCÍA LÓPEZ

  Generalmente el orden suele ser inverso: SEPÚLVEDA MENDEZ, PAOLA

  Posteriormente puedes separar nombres y apellidos usando `split`:

  ```
  i = lb.curselection()[0]
  noms, apells = lb.get(i).split(', ')
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM propietarios WHERE p_nombres = %s AND p_apellidos = %s", (noms, apells))
  ```
- Si esto no te convence podrias construir un diccionario donde la clave sea el nombre tal y como aparece en tu ListBox y los valores sean tuplas o diccionarios conteniendo el nombre y el apellido separados:

  ```
  _propietarios = dict() #Variable/atributo global que contendrá los nombres

  def cargar_lista():
      try:
          connect.commit()
          cursor.execute("SELECT p_nombres, p_apellidos FROM propietarios order by p_nombres")
          registros = cursor.fetchall()
          lb.delete(0, END)
          for item in registros:
              nombres = item[0]
              apellidos = item[1]
              nombre_completo = nombres + ' ' + apellidos
              _propietarios[nombre_completo] = [nombres, apellidos]
              lb.insert(END, nombre_completo)
      except:
          showerror ("Mensaje", "Error al cargar los propietarios.")
  ```

  Ahora en el momento de obtener los datos para pasar la consulta a la base de datos no usamos `valor = lb.get(i)` simplemente, sino que usamos el diccionario:

  ```
  i = lb.curselection()[0]
  valor = lb.get(i)
  noms, apells = _propietarios[valor] #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM propietarios WHERE p_nombres = %s AND p_apellidos = %s", (noms, apells))
  ```

Te recomiendo no construir tus comandos de consulta a la base de datos como variables str de Python crudas, y mucho menos usar los métodos de Python para formatearlos `%`, `str.format()`, etc. Te expones tu base de datos a ataques de inyección. Me refiero a usar:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM propietarios WHERE p_nombres = '%s'", (valor))
```

en vez de:

```
edit = """SELECT * FROM propietarios WHERE p_nombres=("%s");""" % (valor)
cursor.execute(edit)
```

Por otro lado, presuponemos que no pueden existir en ningún momento dos personas con los mismos nombres y apellidos, es decir no puede haber dos PAOLA SEPÚLVEDA MENDEZ.

Comment: La segunda opción me parece más adecuada, aunque la primera cumple con la misma función de otra manera e igual sirve. Pero al aplicar la sugerencia con el diccionario me arroja error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in call return self.func(*args) File "F:\SBIENES\mod\propietarios.py", line 771, in callback llenar_campos() File "F:\SBIENES\mod\propietarios.py", line 775, in llenar_campos nombres, apellidos = _propietarios[i] #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< KeyError: 0

Comment: @Einnerlink yo también creo que el uso del diccionario es mejor, sobretodo es más flexible. En cuanto al error, ha sido algo tonto por mi parte, al diccionario hay que pasarle el valor del elemento seleccionado en el ListView (`nombres, apellidos = _propietarios[valor]`), le estaba pasando el indice.... Lo he corregido en la respuesta. Puede que exista algún error más ya que no puedo reproducir el código por la base de datos, cualquier cosa comentalo. Saludos.

Comment: Funciona, pero el error ahora es: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\SBIENES\mod\propietarios.py", line 768, in callback
    llenar_campos()
  File "F:\SBIENES\mod\propietarios.py", line 832, in llenar_campos
    nombres.set(d6)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: Hay campos tipo Int y String que se cargan pero otros no.

Comment: @Einnerlink el problema es que he sobrescrito tus Entry `nombres` y  `apellidos ` con mi variable `nombres` sin darme cuenta en la función `llenar_campos()`. Solo hay que cambiar el nombre de las variables:  `nombres, apellidos = _propietarios[valor] ` por algo como  `noms, apells = _propietarios[valor]` y hacer lo propio en el query a la base de datos. Corregido en la respuesta. A ver ahora como te funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Excelente! Eso me sirvió! @FJSevilla

Answer (score 0):

Hola buen día hice el ejemplo con mi tabla en mysq y me cuando uso el `.set` del obejeto que es un Entry me da error pero cuando a los datos los muestro con un `print` me los muestra. es como que hay un conflicto aquí `codigo.set(d1)` y en los sucesivos. El error es el siguiente.

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "/home/luis/Python/ConexionBaseValidacionMB", line 72, in
>   buscar_registro
>       codigo.set(d1) AttributeError: Entry instance has no attribute 'set' [Finished in 557.4s]

Desde ya muchas gracias. Abrazo.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/206278)

Comment: Ya lo solucioné reemplazando "codigo.set(d1)" por "codigo.insert(0,d1)".